# Replacing IN clause by EXISTS causes unexpected results

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

Given a simple table lieu_horaire with :

```
+ id_horaire (numeric)
+ id_lieu (numeric)
+ horaire (timestamp)
```

Following query works fine at the moment :

```
         DELETE FROM lieu_horaire where id_horaire IN ( 
         SELECT id_horaire "+
         FROM ( 
                SELECT id_horaire,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_lieu order by horaire desc) AS line_number
                FROM lieu_horaire
        ) as sr
        WHERE sr.line_number > 10);
```

But due to scalability reasons, I would like to replace IN clause by `EXISTS '... WHERE EXISTS(... '`. But with exists, instead of deleting the correct lines, it removes all the lines as if `'... WHERE sr.line_number...'` expression were not present.

Comment: Can you explain what you intend to accomplish using the query?

Comment: For each id_lieu in table, all rows which are not among the ten more recent are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have joined the column while using exists , something like this:

```
DELETE FROM lieu_horaire where exists ( 
     SELECT id_horaire
     FROM ( 
            SELECT id_horaire,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_lieu order by horaire desc) AS line_number
            FROM lieu_horaire
    ) as sr
    WHERE sr.line_number > 10 **and lieu_horaire.id_horaire=sr.id_horaire**);
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. More or less the same  performance in lower to average row deletion (less than 5 000 000), but better beyond (on my test computer). And I think there is no limitation like IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplification using `NOT IN`:

```
DELETE FROM lieu_horaire lh
    WHERE lh.id_horaire NOT IN (SELECT lh2.id_horaire
                                FROM lieu_horaire lh2
                                WHERE lh2.id_lieu = lh.id_lieu
                                ORDER BY lh2.horaire DESC
                                LIMIT 10
                               );
```

However, I don't know that the performance will be much better.  For either version, you want an index on `lieu_horaire(id_lieu, horaire)`.

If a large number of rows were to be deleted, I might suggest `truncate`/`insert` instead.

Comment: I tried, performance are lower than previous request. I think it has to make a sub query for every id_lieu group instead of just one query.

Comment: @chd . . . Is that true even with the index?

Comment: Yes, even with the index, by far.